# Differences between pseudocolor plot and heatmap?

Tags: visualization, matplotlib, plotting, heatmap

I found some materials using the word `**pseudocolor plot**' and I think that it's just a **heatmap**. Is there any difference between them?

Answer (score 1):

A heatmap is effectively a pseudocolor plot with labelled rows and columns. So, basically heatmap is a pseudocolor plot based on a pandas DataFrame rather than a matrix. Basic difference is in the plotting methods available but you can convert the matrix to dataframe and vice-versa.

Reference :

- [Pseudoplot](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/pcolor.html#:%7E:text=A%20pseudocolor%20plot%20displays%20matrix,cells%20(known%20as%20faces).&text=Of%20the%20four%20vertices%2C%20the,y%2Dcoordinates%20for%20the%20vertices.)
- [Heatmap](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html)